# Start & end Date - Round down

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Good Morning, Hope somebody will be able to assist me with this function, I am currently using Moment.js to calculate the actual Duration between start and end date, which works perfectly , my struggle is to round down the duration to 2 decimals. hope somebody can assist me. This is what I get in return, i would like it to show 19.95 days.

```
  function doDurationCalculation(issueData, journalData, cbAsync) {
        //Check End & Start Date.

        resultData.actualDuration = moment(resultData.actualEndDate).diff(resultData.actualStartDate, 'hours' ) / 24;
        logger.trace("Duration Calculation = " + resultData.actualDuration + " Days " +  ", "  + " actualEndDate =  "
            + resultData.actualEndDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ", "
            + " actualStartDate = " + resultData.actualStartDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD") );
        cbAsync(null, resultData, journalData, issueData);
    },
```

{
    "actualStartDate": "2015-11-05T09:39:05.239Z",
    "actualEndDate": "2015-11-25T09:29:54.210Z",
    "actualDuration": 19.958333333333332
}

Comment: `+(resultData.actualDuration.toFixed(2))` is one way - `Math.round(resultData.actualDuration * 100)/100` is the more traditional way

Comment: Thanks so much :) I Got it fixed! much appreciated